# Storing three integer values

Tags: algorithm, c, unit-testing, homework, integer

> Consider an 8-bit complier, in which we have an integer of size, say
>   2-words i.e. 16-bits or 2 bytes. You need to store three integer
>   values which are supposed to be as:
>
> > ```
> > Name        Range       Size Required
> > --------------------------------------------------
> > Integer 1    0-3        2bits (00-11   in binary)
> > Integer 2    0-5        3bits (000-101 in binary)
> > Inetger 3    0-7        3bits (000-111 in binary)
> > ```
>
> In total, we need only 8 bits to store all of these three values.
>   Which means that a single variable of integer datatype has enough
>   memory to accommodate these values. The challenge is to store all of
>   these three variables into a single instance of integer datatype and
>   retrieve it whenever required.
>
> In other words, you need to develop a program which can - at the
>   maximum - use only two instances of integer datatype, first one for
>   the purpose of scanning values from the standard input device say
>   keyboard and the second one to store the data entered by user in the
>   form of three integer variables as discussed above and print them by
>   retrieving it from the second instance in which the data was stored.

This is my program with no input validation.  Please review it.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
void test();
#endif

#define store(_out, _in, _pos) ((_out) |= ((_in) << (_pos)))
#define ret(_out, _pos, _mask) (((_out) >> (_pos)) & (_mask))

#define firstnum_pos  0
#define secondnum_pos 2
#define thirdnum_pos  5

#define firstnum_mask  0x3
#define secondnum_mask 0x7
#define thirdnum_mask  0x7

int main()
{
  unsigned short input = 0, output = 0;
  printf ("Enter first number:");
  scanf ("%hu", &input);
  store(output, input, firstnum_pos);
  printf ("Enter second number:");
  scanf ("%hu", &input);
  store(output, input, secondnum_pos);
  printf ("Enter third number:");
  scanf ("%hu", &input);
  store(output, input, thirdnum_pos);

  printf ("first  number: %d", ret(output, firstnum_pos, firstnum_mask));
  printf ("second number: %d", ret(output, secondnum_pos, secondnum_mask));
  printf ("third  number: %d", ret(output, thirdnum_pos, thirdnum_mask));

#ifdef DEBUG
  test();
#endif

  return 0;
}

#ifdef DEBUG
void test()
{
  int i,j,k;
  short out;
  for (i=0; i<=3; i++)
    for (j=0; j<=5; j++)
      for (k=0; k<7; k++)
        {
          out = 0;
          store(out, i, firstnum_pos);
          store(out, j, secondnum_pos);
          store(out, k, thirdnum_pos);
          assert (i == ret(out, firstnum_pos, firstnum_mask));
          assert (j == ret(out, secondnum_pos, secondnum_mask));
          assert (k == ret(out, thirdnum_pos, thirdnum_mask));
        }
  printf ("Test completed\n");
}
#endif
```

Comment: Checked this code in both little endian and big endian machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. I'd try encapsulating the position and mask parameters to one parameter. Maybe a struct would be fine for this. It is easy to mix up the parameters of `ret`, for example, somebody could call it accidentally with

   ```
   `ret(output, secondnum_pos, firstnum_mask)`
   ```

   or with

   ```
   `ret(output, firstnum_mask, firstnum_pos)`.
   ```

   (Note the parameter order.)
2. Consider writing tests which store the `i`, `j`, `k` values in different order. Currently they do not detect if storing at the `firstnum_pos` overrides the second or the third values.
3. Consider making copies of `i`, `j` and `k` for the `assert` calls before you call the marcos. If a macro accidentally changes values of `i`, `j` or `k` the assert will not detect it.
4. A unit testing framework would be better for the testing: [Unit Testing C Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65820/unit-testing-c-code)

Answer (score 1):

Your code only works if the bits are not set. If you set the value multiple times, it will not work correctly.